# How many ways are there to put 3 white rooks and 5 black rooks on an 8x8 chessboard, so none can attack each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've been trying to figure it out by using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031629/how-many-ways-are-there-to-position-two-black-rooks-and-two-white-rooks-on-an-8x) solution as an example. I understand it pretty well, but can't wrap my mind around 3 white rooks and 5 black rooks instead of just 2 and 2.

Comment: Clarification required on whether same-colour rooks attacking each other is included or excluded.

Comment: @Joffan I believe that same-color rooks attacking each other is excluded, so user73985 has the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the white rooks first. There are several cases:

1. All three white rooks on the same row or column. There are $16* {8\choose 3}$ ways of doing this, leaving $7*5 = 35$ squares free for the black rooks. So there are $16*{8\choose3}*{35\choose5}$ possibilities here.
2. Two white rooks on the same row, two on the same column. (I.e. one rook shares a row with one of the other two and a column with the third). There are $8 * {8 \choose 2} * 14$ ways of doing this, and it leaves $64 - 8 - 7 - 7 - 6 = 36$ squares free for the black rooks, so there are $8 * {8 \choose 2} * 14*{36 \choose 5}$ possibilities here.
3. Two white rooks on the same row or column, the remaining rook not sharing row or column with either of them. There are $16 * {8 \choose 2} * (64-8-7-7)$ ways of doing this, and leave $64-8-7-7-7-5 = 30$ squares free for the black rooks, so $16 * {8 \choose 2}*42*{30 \choose 5}$ possibilities here.
4. All three white rooks on different rows and columns. There are $(64 * 49 * 36)/6$ possibilities, and leave $25$ squares free for the black rooks, so $64 * 49 * 6 * {25 \choose 5}$ possibilities here.

Total number of possibilities is 
$$16*{8\choose3}*{35\choose5} + 8 * {8 \choose 2} * 14*{36 \choose 5} + 16 * {8 \choose 2}*42*{30 \choose 5} + 64 * 49 * 6 * {25 \choose 5}$$

Comment: Good analysis even though I understand the question differently

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In case 4, why is the third rook represented as 36/3 instead of just 36?

Comment: @LarsHoneytoast It's dividing the whole $64*49*36$ by 3 to reflect not distinguishing between the three white rooks. Except it should be $3! = 6$. Oops. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

$8! {8 \choose{5}}$

You can just permute the numbers 1..8, and select 5 out of 8 rooks to be black.

Comment: I think rooks of the same color won't attack each other

Comment: Ok, mislead by 'none can attack each other'. Please replace with 'no white or black rook attacks each other'. Still that does not explain the accepted answer in that thread. Two white rooks would have $64 \choose 2$ placements.

Comment: @Pieter21 I understand the question the same way as you did.

Comment: Yep, but indeed the accepted answer is clearly the correct one.